# How can I check whether a tkinter window exists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have written this code in python 2.7. here i have created a button named message. whenever i click on this button, a new window is created. Now i want to check a condition that if new window (which appears after clicking the button) exist, show a pop-up that a window of same type exist. and if there is no window of same type, new window should be created.

```
from Tkinter import *

def message():
    m_root = Tk()

    entry_value = StringVar()

    m_label = Label(m_root, text="message")
    m_label.pack()

    frame1 = Frame(m_root)
    frame1.pack()
    frame2 = Frame(m_root)
    frame2.pack()

    entry_box = Entry(frame1, width=30, bd=5)
    entry_box.pack()

    button1 = Button(frame2, text="Comment")
    button1.pack(side="left")

    m_root.mainloop()

root = Tk()

root.geometry('150x30+1+1')
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)

comment_button = Button(root, text="Comment", command = message, bg="gray", width=10)
comment_button.pack(anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the existence of a window using the `winfo_exists()` method of the widget object.

However, you should not be calling `Tk()` again in the message function. Instead we have `Toplevel` for new toplevel windows (ie dialogs). A toplevel has an owner which can be the Tk root window or other application window. This way the window manager will see the proper hierarchy of windows.

It is also good to set the dialog toplevel as transient for its parent (`dlg.wm_transient(root)`) so that the window manager only shows a taskbar icon for the application root and not for every dialog it creates.

#### EDIT

A modified example follows to show how to use Toplevel and wm_transient for this purpose, along with a grab to make a modal dialog and placing the new dialog on top of the parent widget. (This uses python3 as that is what I have).

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def show_dialog(parent):
    dlg = tk.Toplevel(parent)
    dlg.wm_title("Dialog box")
    dlg.wm_transient(parent)

    frame = ttk.Frame(dlg)
    label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Message:")
    entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=30)
    button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Comment")

    label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='NEWS')
    entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NEWS')
    button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='NEWS')

    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NEWS')
    dlg.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    dlg.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    entry.focus()
    dlg.grab_set()
    dlg.tk.eval('tk::PlaceWindow {0} widget {1}'.format(dlg, parent))

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('320x120')
    root.wm_title("Demo application")
    comment_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Comment", command=lambda: show_dialog(root))
    comment_button.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I am new in python so can you please add the updated code according to your concept and i am also confused that where to put my condition to check that whether a window exists or not. @patthoyts

Comment: @AnupamYadav added example using python3

Comment: thanks @patthoyts . its working. but can you please tell me the meaning of following line- "dlg.tk.eval('tk::PlaceWindow {0} widget {1}'.format(dlg, parent))"